# How to precisely move a flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If we have two elements like this:

```
<main style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
</main>
```

How do we move `div 2` up `5px` relative to where it is currently at?

Comment: put position:relative, top:-5px in div2 class

Comment: Try `margin-top` like this: `<div style="margin-top:-5px">2</div>`

Comment: The `position: relative` does the trick!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS `position` property. It allows you to move an element within a document.

The actual positioning is done using the CSS offset properties `right`, `left`, `top` and `bottom`.

In your particular case, `position: relative` should do the trick.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

div:last-child {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}

/* demo styles */
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</main>
```

More details: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/